# Odoo 9 Salary Rule based on country

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to define a **salary rule** in Odoo 9 Payroll.

The rule **condition** has to be based on the employee's country. I tried the python expression code below but it does not work.

`result = (employee.country_id=="Malaysia") or False`

I'm aware that the field type of employee's country (nationality) is `many2one` with relation of `res.country`. I just couldn't figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
result = (employee.country_id.name == "Malaysia") or False
```

Answer (score 0):

***employee.country_id*** will return you the object of res.country table with respective record but you need to extend ***employee.country_id.name*** to get the character name field from database record.